# Magento 2: How to add a tab in admin form using layout blocks where form is created by uiComponent

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, grid-layout

I am using uiComponent to create admin form, I am facing a situation where I have to add a tab using layout blocks, so I have updated my layout with following code.

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <uiComponent name="ui_component_file_name"/>
</referenceContainer>
<referenceContainer name="left">
    <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs" name="name_edit_tabs">
        <action method="addTab">
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">products</argument>
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Products</item>
                <item name="title" xsi:type="string">Products</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="helper" helper="Custom\Module\Helper\Data::getProductsGridUrl"></item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">ajax</item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

I get following result, the grid is opening under left area

[image]

and my tab created by uiComponent is shifted below.

[image]

What I am doing wrong? I would like to display uicomponent-created tab default open and a tab created by layout block below.

I also tried my own block `Custom\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tabs` replacing `Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs` with following code.

Tabs.php

```
namespace Custom\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit;

class Tabs extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs
{
    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('page_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Products'));
    }
}
```